# How to save the html source code while navigating to each link

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
path = "/home/winpc/test/python/dup/new"
def get_link_urls(url,driver):
    driver.get(url)
    url = urllib.urlopen(url)
    content = url.readlines() 
    urls = []
    for link in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
        source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
        test = link.get_attribute('href')
        if str(test) != 'None':
               file_name=test.rsplit('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
               file_name_formated = file_name + "Copy.html"
               with open(os.path.join(path, file_name_formated), 'wb') as temp_file:
                    temp_file.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
        urls.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
    return urls

urls = get_link_urls("http://localhost:8080",driver)
sub_urls = []
for url in urls:
    if str(url) != 'None':
        sub_urls.extend(get_link_urls(url,driver))
```

This code properly navigating each and every link but all the time coppiny only the first html page.I need to save the source code of each and every page navigating.saving part is happening using below code:

```
file_name_formated = file_name + "Copy.html"
with open(os.path.join(path, file_name_formated), 'wb') as temp_file:
                temp_file.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: so what is your exact question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're overwriting URL again and again in the function, so fix that one.

For saving page source through selenium, you can use `driver.page_source`

Additionally, if you want this code to be faster, consider using requests module.

```
response = requests.get(url).content
```

Comment: Best and neatest would be to use BeautifulSoup's beautify function.

Comment: please can you provide the complete code.What is request here?What is content here?

Comment: Actually i need to save with dynamically changed source page

Comment: In that case, specify what exactly changes dynamically. requests is a 3rd party module which is like a faster and more powerful version of urllib2. request.get(url).content returns a response object which contains the page source of the url.

Comment: In py3 you need to do a .content.decode('utf-8') to the request.

Comment: How is the relevant here? And no, it's not required in all cases.